# In a domain-driven microservice, should you communicate outside the domain?

Tags: microservices, domain-driven-design

If my company sole purpose is processing a specific payload, but there is lot of orchestration for it. Should the orchestration, be in a separate domain. Lets say, payment is what the company does, but there is a workflow service, for that payment payload? If that is in a seperate domain, how should the workflow service domain talk to payment service domain?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use [Event Driven Design](https://martinfowler.com/articles/201701-event-driven.html) which powered by message services like RabitMQ (or Kafka, MSMQ, or ..). It's not recommended to speech microservice each other directly via APIs. On the other hand to aggregate, some information from multiple services you can use 2 techniques, first using a [BFF](https://tsh.io/blog/design-patterns-in-microservices-api-gateway-bff-and-more/) (back end for frontend layer), Second use a materialized view to gather information from many services.